# Cannot read property '0' of undefined when install directive angular 2

Tags: angular, npm

i trying to install this in the cmd like this:

```
PS C:\Users\moshel\Workspaces\Aman.Magar.Maply\WebUI> npm install @ngui/auto-complete --save
```

but i get this result:

> npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 requires a peer of
>   @angular/compiler@4.4.3 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.3 but
>   none was installed.
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\moshel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-27T05_43_52_877Z-debug.log

someone know why?

Comment: whats the log that it output?

Answer (score 0):

npm 5.3.0 is broken (on windows 10) for me too after upgrading to nodeJS v8.2.0. Same symptoms/logs as described above. `npm install -g npm@5.2.0` temporarily fixes the problem.